# Visual studio 2017 cpprestsdk for linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cpprest-sdk

I`m trying to build a linux console app for web post(REST) with VS2017.

Can i compile cpprestsdk for linux with VS2017?

Comment: How do you plan VS2017 to work on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse you can.

1. Install Vs2017 with "Linux Development with C++"

   https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WritingAndDebuggingLinuxCApplicationsFromVisualStudioUsingTheWindowsSubsystemForLinux.aspx

   then you can now create and debug with Linux
2. Install cpprestsdk on your Linux Server

   https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux
3. Open [Property] of your VS Project [Linker] -> [Input]

    Add "boost_system; crypto; ssl; cpprest" to the [Library Dependencies].


   Then it works.
   Hope this will help you.